# Можно ли градиент на сайте скачать картинкой?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли градиент на сайте скачать картинкой. То есть у меня градиент на сайте, я нажму на кнопку и скачаю картинку этого градиента.

Comment: Можете попробовать использовать [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas)

Answer (score 0):

Нет, но можно взять gradient код и сгенерировать картинку.
http://angrytools.com/gradient/ копируй gradient код и кликни на сайте на add gradient
потом можно скачать SVG

Comment: нет  мне надо картинкой

Comment: http://svgtopng.com/ загружаешь сгенерированный SVG и получаеюшь картину.